# Animate UINavigationBar when pushing view controller onto stack

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uinavigationbar

The Apple Music app has a nice transition when a view controller with a visible navigation bar ("My Music" view controller) has a view controller with a transparent navigation bar (An artist's view controller) pushed on to the stack.

I'm looking to recreate this transition myself.

I've set the navigationbar to be transparent with the following code:

```
private func _setNavigationBarVisible(isVisible isVisible: Bool)  
{  
    title = nil  


    /* 
        Update the navigation bar's visibility. 

        Create a helper method to prevent running the same code twice. 
     */  
    func _updateNavigationBarVisibility(isVisible isVisible: Bool, userViewController: UserViewController?)  
    {  
        //  Create a dummy navigation bar we can rip the default values out of if it should be visible
        let navigationBar = UINavigationBar()  
        let backgroundImage = isVisible ? navigationBar.backgroundImageForBarMetrics(.Default) : UIImage()  
        let shadowImage = isVisible ? navigationBar.shadowImage : UIImage()  

        userViewController?.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(backgroundImage,  
                                                                                   forBarMetrics: .Default)  
        userViewController?.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = shadowImage  
    }  

    //  Animate alongside the view controller's presentation transition if there is one  
    let isTransitionAnimationRun = transitionCoordinator()?.animateAlongsideTransition({ [weak self] context in  

        _updateNavigationBarVisibility(isVisible: isVisible, userViewController: self)  
    }, completion: nil)  

    //  Or just update the values if there's no transition  
    if isTransitionAnimationRun == false  
    {  
        _updateNavigationBarVisibility(isVisible: isVisible, userViewController: self)  
    }  
}
```

This function is run in my `viewWillAppear:` and `viewWillDisappear:` methods passing `false` and `true` to the `isVisible` parameter respectively.

This code does achieve a similar effect, but despite the code doing what it should, I want a different effect.

Currently, this code animates the shadow image making them visible on both view controllers rather than like Apple Music where only the one that presented it should have the shadow. As for the background image, there's a visible "swipe" animation as the navigation bar's background animates from transparent to translucent.

There's also an issue with the swipe gesture which I am looking in to, but currently if during the swipe gesture you keep your finger in one position so no swiping occurs and then lift the finger, the navigationbar updates as though the swipe finished, but the view controllers become glitched and the stack is never pushed or popped despite using the fully useable navigation bar.